# How to get a field by counting the column ( number of character)

Tags: awk

I have a `logfile.txt` and I want to specify the filed $4 but based on number of column not number of field because the fields are separated by spaces characters and the field 2 (`$2`) may contain a values separated by space. I want to count lines but I don't know how specify `$4` without causing a problem if the field 2 (`$2`) contain a space character.

here is my file:

```
KJKJJ1KLJKJKJ928482711           PIEJHHKIA      87166188177633         AJHHHH77760                00666667        876876800874          2014100898798789979879877770
KJKJJ1KLJKJKJ928482711                HKHG      81882776553868        HGHALJLKA700                00876763        216897879879          2014100898798789979879877770
KJKJJ1KLJKJKJ928482711            UUT UGGT      81762665356426   HGJHGHJG661557008                00778787        268767860704          2014100898798789979879877770
KJKJJ1KLJKJKJ9284827kj            ARTH HGG      08276255534867   HGJHGHJG661557008                00876767        212668767684          2014100898798789979879877770
```

here is the code :

```
awk 'END {  OFS="\t"; for (k in c)      print  c[k],"\t"k,"\t"f[k] }  {   k = $4  c[k]++; f[k]=substr($0,137,8)   }'    logfile.txt
```

I WANT TO COUNT BASED ON field $4. but to specify this field in code we must based on number of character (substr ($0,..,..) :

the output shold be :

```
1   20141008        AJHHHH77760
1   20141008        HGHALJLKA700
2   20141008        HGJHGHJG661557008
```

Comment: Why everything is in the `END` block? What is the expected output? What is the idea of what you are doing? This will help people to understand and find a solution.

Comment: I WANT TO COUNT BASED ON field $4. but to specify this field in code we must based on number of character:

the output shold be :

1 20141008  AJHHHH77760
1 20141008  HGHALJLKA700
1 20141008  JHJHJHHJHHJjua876
1 20141008  HGJHGHJG661557008

Comment: You have asked many questions in the site to know the basics: add the full explanation in the question, not in comments neither in answers. Try to make things easy to people reading your question. It will help us and, more important, it will help you get answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your records are composed of fixed width fields you can use `cut(1)`

```
% cut -c1-22,23-42,43-62,... --output-delimiter=, file | sed 's/, */,/g' > file.csv
% awk -F, '{your_code}' file.csv
```

please write a range for each of your fixed width fields, in place of the `...` ellipsis.
I have written ranges only for the first three, lazy me.

If you don't want to bother with an intermediate file, just use a `|` pipe.

Comment: Unix command line is built around the idea of using little tools that apply transformation to text files, it's just to know the right tool... look also, e.g.,  at `paste(1)`, `split(1)` and `join(1)` for different, similar tasks.